# How to communicate with WEB API in Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

I am working with push notifications in windows phone. Notification channel uri is changing while re installing the app in the windows mobile. so there is a problem to send notification to the channel url.

By using web service i am storing the url in database.

I want to update the uri if it is changed using device id.

To do that, i have a WEB API method [HTTPGET] to check the deviceid availability in the database. It is developed to return True/False.

Now my question is, How can we communicate with the service and how can we handle the web api bool return type using C# in windows phone?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

To communicate with the service with httpget request you have to use HttpClient class
Here how I do:
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string result=await client.GetStringAsync(url);
note that the event which call the web service must be declared async, because the httpclient is purely Asynchronous

Comment: Look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx and there are many other place where you can learn about HttpClient. It is in System.Net.Http library

Comment: Thank You Very Much For Responding. . .The issue has solved as my own... Thank You...